# How to use range slider with django-filter

Tags: django

How can I use a range slider (for example the jQuery one) with `django-filter` package?

I have tried to use `NumericRangeFilter` with new field (I don't know how to overwrite the filter class from one specific field).

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    price = django_filters.NumericRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = 'price'
```

I wish to know how to use the field in the template to render a range slider and filter the results.
I expect too to know how can I change the filter class of just one model field.